# Matlab replace element between 2 matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have two matrix M x N, For simplicity, we take 4x4:

Matrix A:

```
1 4 2 5
4 5 8 2
3 4 5 6
2 3 5 8
```

Matrix B:

```
10 11 12 13
56 11 23 45
34 44 33 25
25 63 35 78
```

If an element of matrix A is greater then 5, then we change it from matrix B.

At the end we must get a matrix C:

```
1 4 2 5
4 5 23 2
3 4 5 25
2 3 5 78
```

How can I make it, should I use something like logical indexing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use logical indexing:

```
C = A;
C(C>5) = B(C>5);
```

This means that every element in `C` that is `>5` is set to the corresponding value in `B`.

or

```
C = A.*(A<=5) + B.*(A>5);
```

The comparisons in the parentheses create arrays with 0 and 1, so the first multiplication sets all elements of `A` to zero that should be taken from `B`, and second multiplication sets all elements of `B` to zero that should be taken from `A`.